# using Provider in nested part of widgets and getting dispose() error

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to using `Provider` to nested my screen page as `TabBarView`. when i try to use

this provider as:
Provider.of(context).getSingleUser()
into parent screen and one page on `TabBarView` in this screen together i get error:

> At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer
>   stable. E/flutter (21506): To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in
>   its dispose() method,  save a reference to the ancestor by calling
>   inheritFromWidgetOfExactType()  in the widget's
>   didChangeDependencies() method.

in main function i defined this providers:

```
...  
MultiProvider(providers: [
  Provider(builder: (_) => database),
  Provider(builder: (_) => database.userTableDao),
  Provider(builder: (_) => settings),
] ...  ,
```

and into `register_navigator.dart` i have `TabBarView` with two children

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: Provider.of<UserTableDao>(context).getSingleUser(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
        UserTableData user = snapshot.data;
        ...
        TabBarView( ... ),
      }

      ...
}),
```

and then on child of this `TabBarView` i used

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: Provider.of<UserTableDao>(context).getSingleUser(),
```

again

WHEN I REMOVE PROVIDER IMPLEMENTATION FROM PARENT OF TabBarView THAT CAUSE OF REOLVING PROBLEM

Comment: Have you called push in some point of this flow?

Comment: I mean, are you navigating to any route?

Comment: Can you provide the full code for tab holder and tab views?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199389/discussion-between-doldurma-and-haroldolivieri).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the problem you're facing is related with a no longer valid context and according to `provider` documentation :

> Alternatively instead of using `Provider.of`, we can use `Consumer` and `Selector`.
>   These can be useful for performance optimizations or when it is difficult to obtain a BuildContext descendant of the provider

So, wrap your `FutureBuilder` inside a `Consumer` instead of using `Provider.of`:

```dart
Consumer<UserTableDao>(
  builder: (_, dao, __) => 
    FutureBuilder(
      future: dao.getSingleUser(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
    ...
```

Comment: @DolDurma my answer worth the bounty?

Comment: could you help how can i use `Provider.of<>.value()` instead of `Consumer`? thanks

Comment: It depends on how your app is constructed and how you pass the context forward. Why do you want to avoid Consumer?

Comment: i want to know how can i implementing that with `Provider.of<>.value()`

Answer (score 2):

If you're providing a value instead of a newly constructed Provider type, then consider using the `Provider.value` constructor. Especially if you want your value to not be disposed after one of the Provided instances goes out of scope.

Comment: That's not value. I'm providing database class and class functions and because of that. I'm not understood how can I solve that

Comment: I suggest you try that and see what it does.

Comment: Your new mean is without using builder in provider I should use  value?

Comment: yes. use the .value names constructor and pass your value you want to provide to it

Comment: i'm not sure because that's class with some functionally  methods. i want to provide class with them

Comment: Yep. That will work fine. I used .value in my architecture until I required dispose functionality

Comment: this is not this correct `return Provider<AppDb>.value(value:UserTableDao(),`. could you provide sample code for me? thanks

Comment: Can't do man. I don't know what return type your objects are so won't be able to help you with that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199316/discussion-between-doldurma-and-filled-stacks).